# changing filename extension

Tags: bash, unix, echo

I'm trying to change a filename extension from .xlsx to .csv.

I had this syntax so far and works just fine.

```
raw_file=test_file.xlsx
echo "${raw_file%.xlsx}.csv"
test_file.csv
```

but if I try to assign .xlsx into variable it doesn't work anymore.

```
f=.xlsx
echo "${raw_file%.$f}.csv"
test_file.xlsx.csv
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nested parameter expansions are _not_ supported in `bash` by default.

Comment: I see. Is there any work around to this?

Comment: @Inian Nested parameter seems to work fine in my shell (Bash 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `basename` command, e.g.

```
raw_file=test_file.xlsx
f=.xlsx
echo $(basename "$raw_file" "$f").csv
# -> test_file.csv
```

But keep in mind that `basename` also removes any leading directory names from the file name.

Comment: this is great. I don't need the leading directory anyway. thank you.

Comment: As @Gordon Davisson mentioned, you have "." both in f and inside the expansion "${raw_file%.$f}.csv". I suggest deleting one of those. While using basename works fine, it is not recommended in case of large data set. basename is separate command and a new process is created every time it is called. In the opposite variable expansion should be more resource friendly as it is builtin feature of your shell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have "." both in the variable (".xlsx") and in the replacement expression (".$f"), so it's trying to remove "..xlsx". You need to put the period in only one of these places, and then it'll work:

```
$ raw_file=test_file.xlsx
$ extwithoutdot=xlsx
$ echo "${raw_file%.$extwithoutdot}.csv"    # Here the "." is in the expression
test_file.csv
$ extwithdot=.xlsx
$ echo "${raw_file%$extwithdot}.csv"    # Here the "." is in the variable
test_file.csv
$ echo "${raw_file%.$extwithdot}.csv"    # Here the "." is in both -- it fails
test_file.xlsx.csv
```